# Hibernate insert="false" not obeyed for composite-element in set

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-mapping

I have a mapping for a set with a `composite-element` where a property has the attribute `insert="false"` set. However, upon saving of the parent object, this attribute seems to be ignored as Hibernate tries to insert it anyway.

What am I missing here? How can I get this to work as expected?

```
<set name="deals" cascade="all,save-update" >
    <subselect>
        ...some select statement...
    </subselect>
    <key column="user_id" />
    <composite-element class="UserDeal">
        <property name="dealId" column="deal_id" type="string" />
        <property name="dealName" column="deal_name" type="string" update="false" insert="false" />
    </composite-element>
</set>
```

In the example above, I don't want the INSERT statement to include the `deal_name` property, but it's still included for some reason.

Comment: could you please share your mapping file